# How to create checkboxes from ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I have an ArrayCollection `[{category: "fiction", title: "The Time Machine", author: "H.G. Wells"},...]` of objects from which I want to create checkboxes that:

1. Are divided into sections with section headers
2. Are displayed horizontally, i.e. the checkboxes appear left to right and continue onto the following line

**Anyone know how to achieve the following display?**

```
FICTION
[] The Sleeper Awakes -- H.G. Wells [] The Time Machine -- H.G. Wells 
[] The Invisible Man -- H.G. Wells  [] War of the Worlds -- H.G. Wells
```

I tried using an itemRenderer, but it didn't quite achieve what I want:

```
<s:Panel id="catalogPanel" width="487" minHeight="300" title="Books">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:List dataProvider="{catalog}" width="100%" height="300">
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout/>
            </s:layout>
            <s:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <s:ItemRenderer>
                        <s:CheckBox id="book" label="{data.title}"/>
                    </s:ItemRenderer>
                </fx:Component>
            </s:itemRenderer>
        </s:List>
    </s:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

2.) The [flexLib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/) project provides a `FlowBox` component for this.